# I can build Armv7 + Arm64 architecture but not Armv7 alone

Tags: xamarin, 64-bit

Building a unified API app (after migration) with Armv7 + Arm64 architecture works fine, and the app runs well on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. but it fails to run on iPhone 4S due to incompatible architecture.

Trying to build it with only Armv7 architecture fails.
These are the errors I get:

Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _res_9_init. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)

Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _xmlDocGetRootElement. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)

And 6 more like these...
how can I compile this on Armv7 only?

Comment: Please add '-v -v -v -v' to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options and pastebin a good and a bad build log.

Comment: http://rumblephonebook.azurewebsites.net/goodBuild.txt

Comment: http://rumblephonebook.azurewebsites.net/badBuild.txt

Comment: Seems like a problem in Oyala binding. But why Armv7+Arm64 is ok and Armv7 is not ok?

Answer (score 1):

The solution:
Armv7 build failed due to missing link flags in the Oyala binding linkWith file.
After fixing the flags (LinkerFlags="-lstdc++ -lz -lxml2 -lresolv") the Armv7 build was completed with no errors.

It still doesn't explain why Armv7+Arm64 (the fat build) did not fail.
It just skipped the Oyala build.
This is probably a Xamarin bug.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Xamarin.iOS, it's not including certain libraries in the fat (armv7+arm64) build, while those (problematic) libraries cause problems in the armv7-only build.

That said, I believe the build problems will be solved by adding `-gcc_flags -lxml` to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options.

In addition I recommend filing a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) for the difference in the fat vs thin builds.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do that and update you about the flags solution.

Comment: After adding -gcc_flags -lxml I get:  Error MT5309: Native linking error: library not found for -lxml (MT5309) (Rumble.Touch)

Comment: Error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -lxml (MT5201) (Rumble.Touch)

Comment: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202) (Rumble.Touch)